How do i get my 3D cube to rotate 45 degrees in any direction?
I am working on a 3D game and I want to get my cube(player) to be able to turn 45 degrees in any direction to give my player the ability to be able to turn. I have seen many ways of doing this online but im not so sure how to implement this with my code the way it is.
My Cube is a 3D cube im not so sure which axis to reference when getting it to turn if it makes more sense i dont want it to rotate downwards or upwards just side-ways like it would if i was a character in a game. What ive got so far is only player movement fowards and backwards left and right.
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#define RAYGUI_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "raygui.h"                 // Required for GUI controls


#include "raylib.h"                 //Main Raylib core library
#include "raymath.h"                //Raylib Math functions library
#include "rlgl.h"                   //RayLib OpenGL library
#define XBOX_ALIAS_1 "xbox"
#define XBOX_ALIAS_2 "x-box"

//information about all our in-game objects------
//Information about our players features
struct Enemy {
    int radius{ 1 };
    float speed{ 0.1 };
    Color enemycolor{ BLACK };
}; Enemy;

//Information about our enemys features
struct Player {
    int width{ 2 };
    int height{ 2 };
    int length{ 2 };
    float speed{ 0.1 };
    Color playercolor{RED};
}; Player;

//information about our bullets features
struct Bullet {
    int width{ 9 };
    int height{ 5 };
    int speed{ 4 };
    Color bulletcolor{ YELLOW };
    bool IsBulletActive;
    int NumOfBullet{ 4 };
}; Bullet;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Program main entry point
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(void)
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - basic window");

    // Define the camera to look into our 3d world-------
    //declaring a 3D camera
    Camera3D camera = { 0 };
    //this is how we set up all the aspects of our 3D camera
    camera.position = Vector3{ 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f };  // Camera position
    camera.target = Vector3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };      // Camera looking at point
    camera.up = Vector3{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };          // Camera up vector (rotation towards target)
    camera.fovy = 50.0f;                                // Camera field-of-view Y
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;             // Camera mode type

    // this is the cubes position on all the axis
    Vector3 cubePosition = { 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f };

    // this is the cones position on all the axis
    Vector3 SpherePosition = { 0.0f, 3.0f, -6.0f };
    
    // this represents the cameras displacement and the vectors inside will determine how much the other vectors will be displaced by   
    Vector3 displacement = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    //speed of our cameras movement
    double cameraspeed = 0.3;

    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int gamepad = 0; // which gamepad to display

    Player player;

    Enemy enemy;

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        //Update--

        //This is where we set up camera movement and x box controller---
        if (IsGamepadAvailable(gamepad)){
            //linking our displacement to our x box controller triggers and adding in our camera speed 
            displacement.x = (GetGamepadAxisMovement(gamepad, GAMEPAD_AXIS_RIGHT_X) * cameraspeed);
            displacement.y = (GetGamepadAxisMovement(gamepad, GAMEPAD_AXIS_LEFT_Y) * cameraspeed);
            displacement.z = (GetGamepadAxisMovement(gamepad, GAMEPAD_BUTTON_LEFT_FACE_UP) * cameraspeed);
        }

        //making our camera position vectors equal to the displacement making it move the camera angle
        camera.position.x += displacement.x;
        camera.position.y += displacement.y;
        camera.position.z += displacement.z;

        //Code for player movement
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_DOWN)) {

            cubePosition.z += enemy.speed;
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)) {

            cubePosition.z -= enemy.speed;
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) {

            cubePosition.x += enemy.speed;
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) {
             
            cubePosition.x -= enemy.speed;
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A)) {

            cubePosition.y -= enemy.speed;
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_Z)) {

            cubePosition.y += enemy.speed;
        }
        
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();
        
        DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);

        //Setting our background to a blank canvas
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        //This activates our camera in our level
        BeginMode3D(camera);

        //3D drawing of our player as a cyllinder-----
        //Drawing our 3D Cyllinder 
        DrawSphere(SpherePosition, enemy.radius, enemy.enemycolor);

        //3D drawing of enemy as a cube----
        //Drawing our 3D cube
        DrawCube(cubePosition, player.width, player.height, player.length, player.playercolor);

        //Draws the grid in our level
        DrawGrid(40, 0.5f);

        //This is deactivating our 3D camera
        EndMode3D();

        //This ends our code 
        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
};


Please edit your question and add a tag for the coding language you're using.  This will help get your question in front of the right people. Also, if there's a way to reduce your code to a minimal, reproduceable example of your problem, it would help so others don't have to weed through your code to determine where the problem is.

How much do you know about linear algebra and maxtrix multiplications to model affine transofrmations? If the answer is not much, lookup material on those topics online.

Whittle down your program to something that draws a cube, then rotates it 45 degrees, the draws it again.  Get this working and if there are issues, create a new question and post to StackOverflow.
